# SharePoint 2013: can a user see a list and its metadata, but not be allowed to open the documents?

Tags: document-library, permissions

Is it possible to let a user in SharePoint 2013

- view a list of documents (and their metadata),
- but not allow him to open, display or download the corresponding documents?

If the answer should be "no":
is there a workaround possible to automatically export the document list with metadata, if it changes, and give the user access to this exported list?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by writing javascript in the page when my manager asked me to.
Drop a script editor in the page and make those items not clickable so user won't be able to interact with items at all.

But the better solution will be using a Content Search Web Part and customized the template, or edit the view for library from SharePoint Designer.